# tomcat 8.5 servlet parameter: webappBasePath

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I have a web-application having a couple of servlets and one servlet makes an assumption about the init-param `webappBasePath` in `ServletConfig`. I have no idea how this is set, but older versions (eg. tested on tomcat 5 on centos 5 host) `tomcat5-5.5.23-0jpp.40.el5_9` appended './' to the `webappBasePath`, while newer versions do not seem to do this. (**EDIT:** There is no appending of './' to the variable, the code below calls `ServletContext.getRealPath()` to the default setting '.' and different tomcat version handle things differently)

I've added a new servlet to WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>TKServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlets.TKServlet</servlet-class>

    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>TKServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/tkservlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

TKServlet.java

```
package ImageGenerator;

import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import java.io.*;

public class TKServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9830958231344L;

    private static String webappBasePath = ".";

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
        if (config.getInitParameter("webappBasePath") != null) {
            webappBasePath = config.getInitParameter("webappBasePath");
            System.err.println("init-param 'webappBasePath' = " + webappBasePath);
        }
        webappBasePath = config.getServletContext()
                             .getRealPath(webappBasePath) + "/";
        System.err.println("getRealPath(webappBasePath) = " + webappBasePath);
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.setContentType("text/ascii");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("Here is some response doc.");
        out.println("webappBasePath is: " + webappBasePath);
    }
}
```

**Logs from tomcat5: `http://localhost:8080/myapp/tkservlet`**

catalina.out:

```
getRealPath(webappBasePath) = /usr/share/tomcat5/webapps/XSLT_HIQ/./
```

**Log on tomcat8.5:**

```
getRealPath(webappBasePath) = /adtech/tomcat/webapps/XSLT_HIQ/
```

**Question:** Where is the `webappBasePath` set and how can i modify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer: I guess, i was just confusing myself. Please see my answer, if you're interessted.

The catalina.out logs show that the init-parameter `webappBasePath` is not set at all: If it was, there would have been: `init-param 'webappBasePath' = <something>` message in the `catalina.out` logfile.

One thing to note is, that the output of the `ServletContext.getRealPath()` is different between the tomcat versions, i guess this is a bug in my servlet code.

Of course, it can be set via `<init-params>` in the `WEB-INF/web.xml` file.

I've added (inside the `<servlet>` tag):

```
     <init-param>
        <param-name>webappBasePath</param-name>
        <param-value>/var/tmp/somewebapp/files/./</param-value>
     </init-param>
</servlet>
```

**tomcat 5 log show**

```
init-param 'webappBasePath' = /var/tmp/somewebapp/files/./
getRealPath(webappBasePath) = /usr/share/tomcat5/webapps/XSLT_HIQ/var/tmp
                                  /somewebapp/files/./
```

**tomcat8.5 log**

```
init-param 'webappBasePath' = /var/tmp/somewebapp/files/./
getRealPath(webappBasePath) = /adtech/tomcat/webapps/XSLT_HIQ/var/tmp
                                  /somewebapp/files//
```

**NOTE** `ServletContext.getRealPath()` on tomcat8.5 is 'normalising' the path by removing a single dot component.

**EDIT**

Older tomcat versions where using the following code in `ApplicationContext` (example from [svn tc5.0.x](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/archive/tc5.0.x/trunk/))

```
public String getRealPath(String path) {                                    
    // ...                                                                        
    File file = new File(basePath, path);                                   
    return (file.getAbsolutePath());                                        

}
```

While newer verions are using `getRealPath` from `StandardContext` (lines 4319-4349 [here](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/8fd5d6273099c504e1739080c07cf4d33cff89bf/java/org/apache/catalina/core/StandardContext.java))

```
public String getRealPath(String path) {
    if (resources != null) {
        // ...
            WebResource resource = resources.getResource(path);
            String canonicalPath = resource.getCanonicalPath();
            // ...

                return canonicalPath;
            }
    // ...
}
```

The WebResource `getCanonicalPath()` calls `java.io.File#getCanonicalPath()` which

> removes redundant names such as '.' and '..' from the pathname

(copied from [javadocs for File#getCanonicalPath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalPath()))